# Azure Monitoring filter based on OS

Tags: azure

I want to filter my alerts based on OS to aviod having to add a machine to the alerts. I think filtering based on OS should do what I want

Here is my query

```
// enter a GB value to check
let setgbvalue = 5;
// Query
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes"
| where InstanceName !contains "D:"
| where InstanceName !contains "_Total"  
| where InstanceName !contains "HarddiskVolume"
| extend FreeSpaceGB = CounterValue / 1024
| summarize FreeSpace = min(FreeSpaceGB) by Computer, InstanceName
| where FreeSpace < setgbvalue
| where OperatingSystemFullName has "Server" | distinct Computer

VMComputer 
| where OperatingSystemFullName contains_cs "Server" | distinct Computer
```

Here is the error I get based on this query

```
'where' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'OperatingSystemFullName'
```

Comment: Query could not be parsed at 'VMComputer' on line [14,0]

Token: VMComputer
Line: 14
Position: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done repro in our local environment, the below statements are based on our analysis.

> 'where' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named
> 'OperatingSystemFullName'

**Perf** Table, doesn't have any column with **OperatingSystemFullName** that is the reason you are landed up with an above error when you ran the above shared Perf query.

If you want to configure the alert based on OS you need to use **join** for both **Perf & VMComputer** tables  as shown below :

```
let setgbvalue = 5;
VMComputer 
| where OperatingSystemFullName contains "Server"| distinct Computer,OperatingSystemFullName
| join kind = inner ( Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes"
| where InstanceName !contains "D:"
| where InstanceName !contains "_Total"  
| where InstanceName !contains "HarddiskVolume"
| extend FreeSpaceGB = CounterValue / 1024
| summarize FreeSpace = min(FreeSpaceGB) by Computer, InstanceName
| where FreeSpace > setgbvalue) on Computer
```

**Here is the Sample Output for reference:**

[image]

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#join-flavors) documentation, for more information about joins flavors in KQL.